# Чи існує український відповідник запозиченим бутербродові та канапці?

Tags: синоніми, запозичені-слова

Етимологічний словник української мови зазначає, що слово *бутерброд* є запозиченим з німецької (Butter - масло, та Brot - хліб). А відоме на західній Україні *канапка* - запозичення з польської. Також на Вікіпедії в статті про [канапку](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0) зустріла слово накладанець. [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/buterbrod) також пропонує цей варіант, як український відповідник бутерброда, хоча ніде в словниках це слово не зареєстровано. Чи існує український відповідник запозиченим бутербродам та канапкам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово ["Тартинка"](http://sum.in.ua/s/tartynka) згідно до СУМу одначає: "Скибочка хліба, намазана маслом", тобто це той самий "бутерброд". Однак, згідно до сайту [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/buterbrod) та цієї [статті](http://mova.ga/nove_slovo/2657/nakladantsi-zamist-buterbrody-chy-kan/) більш вживаними та популярними варіантами все ж таки є "накладанець" (згадується у "Словнику чужомовних слів і термінів” (1977) П. Штепи та у книжці “Українська мова на лінгвістичній карті Канади” (Київ, Наукова думка, 1990) та "мазанка" (згадується у книжках "Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)" та "Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)).